# Given a remainder and a factor, find a,b and another remainder

Tags: polynomials

$P(x) = (x+1)(x-3)Q(x) + ax + b$

$Q(x)$ is a polynomial where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.

$(x-3)$ is a factor of $P(x)$ and $P(x)$ divided by $(x+1)$ gives a remainder $8$.

Find $a$ and $b$.  Find the remainder of dividing $P(x)$ by $(x+1)(x-3)$.

I worked out that $a(3) + b = 0$ because of the $(x-3)$ factor.  That's really all I can get.  Totally stuck.  Seems like not enough information....

Comment: I am confused.  If $x-3$ is a factor of $P(x)$, then the remainder is 0...

Comment: @boaz: No, then the remainder is divisible by $x-3$ hence $b=-3a$...

Answer (score 1):

You have two conditions here.

You have already figured out the first one: $P(3)=0$, resulting into $3a+b=0$.

The second condition is $P(-1)=8$, resulting into $-a+b=8$.

I think you can find $a$ and $b$ now.